# Software to monitor all Ubuntu systems

Tags: 10.04, software-recommendation, monitoring, landscape

I have more than 150 ubuntu systems connected in a network. Can someone suggest a good monitoring application to monitor all these systems?? For example, I want to check whether all the IPs are up or down and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option I've seen used at several different shops is [xymon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xymon/) .

It was originally a clone of the now non-free "big brother" then changed to "hobbit monitor", before mutating into [xymon](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xymon) [image: Install xymon]
.

It is something like nagios, though in my opinion probably more simple, generally just showing up or down states.  It is very extensible through scripting, however.

[image: xymon monitor up and down systems]

In addition to nagios, other well-known applications include [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) and [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Canonical sells licenses to its [software called Landscape](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape). Free trials are available.

> Landscape is an easy-to-use systems management and monitoring service. Manage multiple Ubuntu machines as easily as one and lower your management and administration costs.

Comment: Any free packages???

Comment: How did I know you'd say that? ;) Not that I know of, but I expect someone else will be able to answer.

Comment: +1 here..Let me wait and check for another response from someone else..

Answer (score 4):

Try nagios, this is great for server management. This software is also free.

Answer (score 0):

We use puppet in conjunction with foreman at our workplace to perform automated deployment and post configuration. It also happens to allow for reporting based on customisable "facts".

Currently the puppet agent on each of our workstations and servers is reporting every 30min, back to our puppetmaster.

Our next tool on this chain will be graphite (and therefore statsd)